# I have problem witch compilation android linux kernel

Tags: kernel, xiaomi, ginkgo

I have a problem with a compilation of Android Linux kernel

```
./include/trace/events/sched.h:269:2: error: #error "Unsupported NR_CPUS for lb tracepoint."
  269 | #error "Unsupported NR_CPUS for lb tracepoint."
      |  ^~~~~
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:362: kernel/fork.o]
```

Comment: use command make